# the Google's code about RenderScript does not work?

Tags: android, renderscript

i find that the google's doc about the RenderScript has update(https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html). so i use it's code to test but o got an error about that

```
Error:(31, 23) error: implicit declaration of function 'rsCreateAllocation_uchar4' is invalid in C99
Error:(31, 17) error: initializing 'rs_allocation' (aka 'struct rs_allocation') with an expression of incompatible type 'int'
```

that is the code:

```
rs_allocation tmp = rsCreateAllocation_uchar4(imageWidth, imageHeight);
rsForEach(invert, inputImage, tmp);
rsForEach(greyscale, tmp, outputImage);
```

so i want to know:
1:why this happen(i think the sdk api is the reason but i have update my AS, SDK and sdk tool to newest)?
2:what's the difference between the

```
uchar4 RS_KERNEL root(uchr4 in, unit32_t x, uint32_t y)
```

and

```
void RS_KERNEL root(uchr4* in, uchar4* out, unit32_t x, uint32_t y)
```

i think the second method is more fast?! but i can't sure.
and the method that using the pointer as params is'n used to a function that not named root()(i test it).so if the method with pointer params is faster how can i use 2 or more kernel function in a RS file?

Comment: What file is generating that error?  That looks like it is coming from a .c or .cpp file rather than .rs.

Comment: it coms from rs file. i take the code from the android developer website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rsCreateAllocation*() functions are only available when targeting Android Nougat (i.e. API level 24 and higher). I assume that you are getting this error because you have chosen a RenderScript target API that is much lower than that.

Comment: thanks i change my build.gradle to:renderscriptTargetApi 24 and it works

Comment: and do you know the difference between the function that using pointers as the params and without it?  i test and find that the function that uchar4 RS_KERNEL invert(uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) is faster than void root(const uchar4 *in, uchar4 *out, uint32_t x, uint32_t y).why? is there any essence difference between this two method? or just the same thing is the underlying algorithm?

Comment: If you pass-by-value (instead of passing the pointers), the compiler can do additional optimizations. With pointers, there is the possibility of aliasing, which precludes our optimizer from doing the best job.

Comment: hi i sorry that i have another question. Is google remove the RenderScript from the NDK? i find some example like: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/rs/+/ee6f190/java/tests/HelloComputeNDK. But that example can not run correct! the same time i can not find any head file and .so file in the android source code.